# convert by function in R to list

Tags: r, list, split

i have data frame that looks like this :

```
is severe   encoding    sn_id
1            1           1
0            2           1
1            2           2
0            1           2
1            1           2
```

im using on  by function this function :

```
catt <-
  function(y, x, score = c(0, 1, 2)) {
    miss <- unique(c(which(is.na(y)), which(is.na(x))))
    n.miss <- length(miss)
    if(n.miss > 0) {
      y <- y[-miss]
      x <- x[-miss]
    }
    if(!all((y == 0) | (y == 1))) 
      stop("y should be only 0 or 1.")
    if(!all((x == 0) | (x == 1) |(x == 2))) 
      stop("x should be only 0, 1 or 2.")
    ca <- x [y == 1]
    co <- x [y == 0]
    htca <- table(ca)
    htco <- table(co)
    A <- matrix(0, 2, 3)
    colnames(A) <- c(0, 1, 2)
    rownames(A) <- c(0, 1)
    A[1, names(htca)] <- htca
    A[2, names(htco)] <- htco
    ptt <- prop.trend.test(A[1, ], colSums(A), score = score)
     #list(#"2x3-table" = A, 
                #chisq = as.numeric(ptt$statistic), 
                #df = as.numeric(ptt$parameter), 
               res= p.value = as.numeric(ptt$p.value)
                #n.miss = n.miss)
    return(res)
    }
```

when i run it :

```
by(es_test,es_test$sn_id, function (es_test) {catt(es_test$ï..is_severe,es_test$encoding)})
```

i get these results:

```
es_test$sn_id: 1
[1] 0.1572992
------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
es_test$sn_id: 2
[1] 0.3864762
```

it is not a very comfortable format as i want to further work with it , is there any way to get these results as list :[0.157,0.386]?

i tried this :

```
result_pv=c(by(es_test,es_test$sn_id, function (es_test) {catt(es_test$ï..is_severe,es_test$encoding)}))
```

but it produced double and i want it as vector or list :

the double :

```
Browse[6]> result_pv
        1         2 
0.1572992 0.3864762 

> typeof(result_pv)
[1] "double"
```

what i want to do with it later is to add this result_pv to data frame as column and when it is a double i cant do that

thank you

Comment: Perhaps `c(by(es_test,es_test$sn_id, function (es_test) {catt(es_test$is_severe,es_test$encoding)}) )` or `as.numeric(by(es_test,es_test$sn_id, function (es_test) {catt(es_test$is_severe,es_test$encoding)}) )
[1] 0.1572992 0.3864762`

Comment: @akrun  it converts it to "double" is there any way to convert it to list ? or vector ?

Comment: It is a numeric vector. `class(as.numeric(by(es_test,es_test$sn_id, function (es_test) {catt(es_test$is_severe,es_test$encoding)}) ))
[1] "numeric"` and ` is.vector(as.numeric(by(es_test,es_test$sn_id, function (es_test) {catt(es_test$is_severe,es_test$encoding)}) ))#
[1] TRUE`